# How to create a child Window When Click on Menu Item in WPF ( C#)

Tags: wpf

I have a question about WPF.
I have a main window include:

1. Left Menu: Some Items such as : Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
2. Right Menu: Content show when I Click on Item 1 or Item 2 or Item 3
   Now, I want to Double Click on Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3, Then a new Window will be shown like Child Window 1, Child Window 2 and Child Window 3. Every item following Child Window Item

What solution I have to do ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please include a [minimal, verifyable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you want, but from what I understood:

A) If you want to launch a same but new window everytime then:

1. Add a new xaml window to your project.
2. Register the double click event for your menu items.
3. Inside the event handler - create the instance of the newly added window like this:

   ```
   Window1 window1 = new Window1();
   window1.Show();
   ```
4. You can pass the data to this window instance inside the handler itself before calling the Show().

B) If you want to launch different windows for different menu items then you have to add that many window files to your project and invoke the appropriate window based on the menu item clicked.